# Double variables multiplication generate extra long wrong value in Java

Tags: java

I have a java code to do a multiplication like this:

TickSize = minTick * AdjustFactor;

They are all double. When the code runs here, the miniSize value is 5.0E-7, AdjustFactor is 100. 
But I get a result as 4.9999999999999996E-5, instead of a 5.0E-5. This is very annoying and break the other module of my software.

The following is the debug message print out right after the above statement is executed.

---

minTick is 5.0E-7 Tick adjust factor is : 100.0 TickSize set to: 4.9999999999999996E-5

---

I wonder if anybody know what is going on? and what I can do to correct it to get result 5.0E-5?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: You are working with double, so you can't ask a super precision. Bu, if you know this, you can change your other code to accept this error.

Comment: There are infinitely many real numbers, but there are fewer than 2^64 possible `double` values, so that means, there are an infinite number of reals that can not be exactly represented by a `double`.  5.0E-5 is one of them.  You _can't_ set TickSize = 5.0E-5.  But, you _can_ get it to print out as "5.0E-5" (or "5.00E-5", or "5.000E-5", or...)  Read about the static function, `String.format(...)` and, the `java.util.Formatter` class that it uses.  You'll want to use the 'e' conversion specifier, and you'll want to pay attention to the "precision" and "width" arguments.